# How can i convert an object to an int in Java?

Tags: java, object, int

I'm working in Java and I would like to convert an `Object` to an `int`.

I do:

```
   Collection c = MyHashMap.values(); 
   Object f = Collections.max(c);
   int NumOfMaxValues = Integer.parseInt(f);
```

But it's not working. It says:
`No suitable method for parseInt.`

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the actual type of `f`?

Comment: Look at the java docs for [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) first!

Comment: What are you inserting into that hash map? Are they integers? If so, just Collection<Integer> c = MyHashMap.values();

Comment: What Object Type do you put in your HashMap?

Comment: Thank you very much, it was really helpful Collection<Integer> c = MyHashMap.values();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

expects a `String`. You can use

```
Integer.parseInt(f.toString())
```

and override the `toString()` method in your class.

Comment: @programmer. Glad to help. Make sure the toString() method returns a valid integer as a string, otherwise an exception will be thrown by parseInt().

Comment: I use the System.out.println() and it outputs and integer. It didn't throw any exception, so its fine.Thanks

Comment: You should almost always use String.valueOf(object) instead of object.toString() since it avoids a NullPointerException in the case of object being null.  In this case you will still get a NumberFormatException for the null case, but since that is being checked / caught anyway, it is better than the unchecked NPE.

Comment: From your comment above, c is a `Collection<Integer>`, yes? In that case, parsing the int isn't wrong, but it's wasteful. `f` is already an `Integer`, which you can assign to an `int` because of autoboxing. `Integer.parseInt(f.toString())` will take that Integer, format it as a String, and then re-parse that back to an int.

Comment: Yes, the values are integers in the collection, Collection <Integer> c = MyHashMap.values();. You are right because if i do : Integer parseInt = (Integer) f; it's working too without the parseInt(f.toString()), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should use generics to your advantage and have something along the lines of the below:

```
Map<Object,Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<Object,Integer>();
Collection<Integer> values = myHashMap.values();
Integer value = Collections.max(values);
if (value != null)
{
  int myInt = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just convert any object to an int. How should that work. Think of a class like this:

```
class Car {
  public String name;
  public String owner;
}
```

You need to define a method yourself. Or you have to find out what specific object that is and how to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt(f.toString());
```